# how to get the unchecked value of a checkbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, input, checkbox

i am developing a attendance system in codeigniter. There is a list of check box. i am successful to insert the checked data to the database but i want to know how will i insert  the unchecked data to the database and how will i detect wither a box is checked or not like java.

here is my view

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" title="Select all" onclick="changeAll(this.checked);"/></th>
    <th>student id</th>
    <th>student name</th>
    <th>class</th>
    <th>section</th>
</tr>
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/student/attendance/submit" onsubmit="return checkForm();" method="post">
<?php foreach($result as $r):?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id[]" value="<?php echo $r->sid ?>"/></td>
    <td><?php echo $id=$r->sid ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $query=$this->db->get('student_basic_info');
            foreach($query->result() as $re){
                echo $re->f_name." ".$re->l_name;
            }
        ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $r->class_name?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->section?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
<tr class="no">
    <td class="no"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="action"></td>
</tr>
    </form>
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814723/passing-checkbox-values-to-mysql-database-using-codeigniter), and run the inserts & deletes in a transaction if you're going to do both on a given form submission!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is add two checkbox as present and absent 
Then loop through each of them and insert the data

Also 
If you want single checkbox then
you can make id_(number) as the checkbox name and send the hidden value of the user id in the same way. At last send the total numbers of the users as hidden tooo.

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach($result as $r):?>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="id_$i" id="id_$i" value="<?php echo $r->sid ?>"/></td>
    <td><?php echo $id=$r->sid ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $query=$this->db->get('student_basic_info');
            foreach($query->result() as $re){
                echo $re->f_name." ".$re->l_name;
            }
        ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $r->class_name?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->section?></td>
</tr>
//Here is the user id 
<input type="hidden" name="user_$i" value="your user id">
<?php

$i++;
endforeach;?>

//now send the total users again in hidden field
<input type="hidden" name="totalusers" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">


//NOw in our php script

for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['totalusers'];$i++){
     if(isset($_POST["id_$i"]))
          //this means the user is present add it to database as your requirement
     else{
         //this means the checkbox was not checked so 
         //for this we get the unchecked users id from $_POST["user_$i"]
         //now add to the database for this user as absent
         }
}
```