# How to insert multiple checkbox value in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am novice in codeigniter. I am trying to insert multiple news that contains some check-box where its values are looped from a database. But i don't know what should code i write for this in controller & Model to insert values. can any one suggest or help me to write code?

view - **content.php**:

```
//category name
<?php foreach($result as $aresult) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category_name[]" value="<?php echo $aresult->category_name;?>" /> <?php echo $aresult->category_name;?>
<?php  } ?>
```

controller - **news**:

```
public function savecontent()
{         
    $data=array();
    foreach($this->input->post('category_name') as $category_name) 
    {
       $data[] = array('category_name' => $category_name);
    }
    $data['content_headline']=$this->input->post('content_headline',true);
    $this->co_model->save_content($data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function save_content($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('content',$data);
}
```

Database structure:

```
id(auto incr.), category_name(varchar 50),  content_headline(varchar 100)
```

now what should i change to insert multiple row using checkbox ? here there have also another text box/column which also insert in database. but only category name(checkbox value) should be change for all value.

Comment: I didn't quite get the last part. Please post the whole relevant code along with your DB structure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing checkbox values to mysql database using Codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814723/passing-checkbox-values-to-mysql-database-using-codeigniter)

Comment: edited question ..please check (geomagas)

Comment: Hmmm not qoute. Apparently, there's another table that holds the categories, the one you use to produce your view. We need that one too! :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to adjust your database structure. Apparently, there's a M:N relation between `content` and `category`. A more appropriate schema would be:

```
create table content (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  content_headline varchar(100) not null
  );

create table category (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  caregory_name varchar(100) not null
  );

create table content_category (
  content int not null references content,
  category int not null references category,
  primary key (content,category)
  );
```

Then, you need to adjust your code to reflect the new schema.

Supposing you get `$result` from a `select * from category`, your view would boil down to:

```
<label>
  Headline:
  <input type='text' name='headline'>
</label>
<?php foreach($result as $aresult): ?>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[<?php echo $aresult->id; ?>]">
    <?php echo $aresult->category_name; ?>
  </label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When posted, this will provide you with an array like the following:

```
array(
  'headline'=>'War and Peace',
  'category'=>array(
    45=>'on',
    6=>'on'
    )
  );
```

...where 45 and 6 are the checked category ids. Please note that, if no category is checked, the `category` array will not be defined.

So the controller becomes:

```
public function savecontent()
  {         
  $post=$this->input->post();
  $selected_cats=(isset($post->category)?array_keys($post->category):array());
  $data=array(
    'headline'=>$post->headline,
    'category'=>$selected_cats
    );
  $this->co_model->save_content($data);
  }
```

And finally, the model:

```
public function save_content($data)
  {
  $this->db->insert('content',array('content_headline',$data['headline']);
  $content=$this->db->insert_id(); // what we inserted
  foreach($data['category'] as $cat)
    $this->db->insert(
      'content_category',
      array(
        'content'=>$content,
        'category'=>$cat
        )
      );
  }
```

Comment: No need to do multiple inserts in a loop. An insert statement can take multiple value sets. Just write the raw sql instead of using the AR lib for CI. The only thing you lose with inserting all at once is transaction granularity, so it depends on if you're worried about errors or not.

Comment: Yea I know, but I chose to play along the lines of the OP... ;)

Comment: No worries, I typically take that route as well. Always like to present the alternative too :)

Comment: $selected_cats=(isset($post->category)?array_keys($post->category):array()); .....what is this line meaning ?

Comment: It's a [ternary operator](http://es1.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary). If `$post->category` is set, then `array_keys($post->category)` is assigned to `$selected_cats`, else an empty array. It's kind of a shorthand `if`.

Comment: here $post=>category (category) is this mean db table? if it, then why i insert category name in category table. i have already some category name in category table and in view page category_name are coming from that table {foreach($result as $aresult)}.. all value should be insert in content table ..like (id, category_name, headline)..sorry if my question is not enough clear for u then u also can check this question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441444/insert-checkbox-value-in-mysql-by-using-codeigniter ..here i write brodly my problem....please check.. & thanks for ur suggessition.

Comment: No, not the db table. It refers to the posted field. See the sample array I provided as an example. It's supposed to contain the checked category ids. And you don't want to insert _only_ into `content` table but also into the new `content_category` relation.